# How to calculate Glide image loading time?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I want to calculate Glide image loading time, but there seems to be no way to get loading time.

Currently, the `RequestListener.onResourceReady` is used to calculate the time, but this is not accurate when the list is swiped or the app is returned to the background.

````
    var start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    placeholder?.let { creator.placeholder(placeholder) }
    error?.let { creator.error(error) }
    creator.config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    creator.fit().into(image,  object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
        override fun onLoadFailed(
            e: GlideException?,
            model: Any?,
            target: Target<Drawable>?,
            isFirstResource: Boolean
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onResourceReady(
            resource: Drawable?,
            model: Any?,
            target: Target<Drawable>?,
            dataSource: DataSource?,
            isFirstResource: Boolean
        ): Boolean {

            var end = System.currentTimeMillis()
            System.out.println(
                "loading_time "+
                        "   photo=" + src + "  start=" + start + "  end=" + end + "   cost=" + (end - start) + "   dataSource=" + dataSource
            )
            return false
        }
    })```
````

Comment: You can easily do that with handlers and some extra logic

Answer (score -1):

Try this logic:

Before loading image take a lateinit long now when before calling glide load function do Handler.postdelay() in that at continuously increment your lateinit long var with 100 milliseconds and when resource is ready just do handler.removecallbacksandmessages() and after that you can print your time.